# Run GUI program on Docker via SSH

Tags: user-interface, docker, ssh, containers, x11

so I have Ubuntu headless server on which I have docker installed.
I would like to run GUI app in Docker container and see them on my mac when I connect via ssh.

I followed instructions from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDg6TRwiPtg)

What i did:
1) install xQuartz on mac
got the auth list cookie:

```
Cyrils-MacBook-Pro.local/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  02f42525dec4a8b4ee2xxxxxx
```

2) connect to my remote server via ssh - X uname@password

3) installed xauth on the server
got the xauth cookie:

```
ubuntu/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  0e6810e9913aca02e0xxxxxxx
```

4) add the xauth cookies to the container: the one from the server and the one from my mac

5) Launch a docker container and installed firefox to test

6) install xauth in the container

7) add the xauth cookies to the container: the one from the server and the one from my mac

8) but when i run firefox (inside the container), i got this error:

```
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Broadway display type not supported: localhost:10.0
Error: cannot open display: localhost:10.0
```

When i do echo $DISPLAY in the container, i have:

```
localhost:10.0
```

When i do echo $DISPLAY in the server, i have:

```
localhost:10.0
```

When i do echo $DISPLAY on my mac, i have:

```
/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.G35gSHS5qU/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
```

I've enable the X11forwarding on my Mac (ssh_config) and my Server (sshd_config) and when i enter my container and launch the GUI app, I got this error:

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
```

The error is obvious, but I don't know how to fix it.
In the container, the cmd xauth list give me:

```
Cyrils-MacBook-Pro.local/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  02f42525dec4a8b4ee2xxxxxx
ubuntu/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  0e6810e9913aca02e0xxxxxxx
```

in the server, the cmd xauth list give me:

```
Cyrils-MacBook-Pro.local/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  02f42525dec4a8b4ee2xxxxxx
ubuntu/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  0e6810e9913aca02e0xxxxxxx
```

in my mac, the cmd xauth give me:

```
Cyrils-MacBook-Pro.local/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  02f42525dec4a8b4ee2xxxxxx
```

Comment: The video is quite old and the docker has evolved a lot in the last few years. Moreover, why do you want to run a GUI app, like Docker is a tool used for running containerized apps.

Comment: i need to run an app that only exist in GUI form, there is no documentation for command line...

Comment: Read this blog and I feel all your queries shall be answered https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/docker-containers-on-the-desktop/